# Error JasperSoft Ubuntu

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

estou com um problema ao executar o JasperSoft 6.4.3 no Ubuntu. A aplicação starta normalmente. Porém quando vou criar um novo relatório, seja com uma base associada ou não, não é exibido nada no relatório (nenhuma das abas: Design, Source e Preview). Também a aba de Outline, não exibe nenhum dos componentes da árvore. Quando dou dois cliques sobre o relatório, na aba da Project Explore, ai aparece uma aba com erro: Could not create the view: Drag Placerholder.

Alguém tem ideia do que pode ser isso. Alguma dependência que precisa ser baixada no linux antes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver baixando outra versão! 6.1.1 foi a que funcionou aqui normalmente.